# "The specified node was not found in the web.config file" - error when trying to add a module programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-config

I try to add a module into the web.config from within an event-receiver. I use `SPWebConfigModification` for this. When I Update the webApp (webApp.Update()) the following error is thrown:

*The specified node "configuration/system.webserver/modules" was not found in the web.config file.*

But that node surely exists in the web config (and also is a quite common node). Any idea why this fails?

```
SPSite currentSite = GetCurrentSite(properties);
currentSite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPWebApplication webApp = currentSite.WebApplication;

SPWebConfigModification modification = new SPWebConfigModification();
modification.Path = @"configuration/system.webServer/modules";
modification.Name = "ErrorRedirectModule";
modification.Sequence = 0;
modification.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
modification.Value = "<add name=\"ErrorRedirectModule2\" type=\"Tools.ErrorHttpModule, Tools, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6e907fc34eb70f91\" />  ";

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    webApp.WebConfigModifications.Add(modification);
    webApp.Update();
    webApp.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the type of `web.config` modification is `EnsureChildNode`, the `Name` property should contain an XPath expression that uniquely identifies the node under the parent node (identified by the `Path` property) to ensure that duplicates of the node are not added to the file.

In other words, `Path` + `Name` must match the XPath expression to the created node.

```
modification.Path = "configuration/system.webServer/modules";
modification.Name = "add[@name='ErrorRedirectModule2']";
modification.Sequence = 0;
modification.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
modification.Value = "<add name='ErrorRedirectModule2' type='Tools.ErrorHttpModule, Tools, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6e907fc34eb70f91' />";
```

I'm not sure about the `'` vs. `"` quotes - it's not consistent even in the MSDN articles I linked below.

More information:

- [Can’t remove web.config entries with SPWebConfigurationModification](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/sharepoint2010programming/thread/d8b5dbe7-d306-4332-83b1-df6e241d419e)
- [How to: Add and Remove Web.config Settings Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861909.aspx)
- [SPWebConfigModification.Name property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.name.aspx)